# %%ChannelUser%% %%ChannelUserEmail%% via bounce.exacttarget.com is display in "From" field

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

Ok - I'm VERY new to Exact Target and when I set up a new account "%%ChannelUser%% %%ChannelUserEmail%% via bounce.exacttarget.com" displays in the "From" email field when it's sent to the customer.

How do I change this to show the accounts email, instead of this?

Comment: Is this in a developer edition account, or a purchased account?